# How to highlight cells when using Excel VBA conditional formatting?

Tags: vba, excel

Okay so I am stuck and would appreciate any help or advice at all.

I am trying to highlight the cells that meet two conditions. That is to say, in this particular case if the absolute value in a cell is greater than 3 and this same absolute value is greater than another value in an adjacent cell then the cell gets highlighted. So for example, my data looks like this:

-1.2,   1.71,   6.26,   10.2,   3.3,    0.4             4   -4

So if the absolute values of any of the six values on the left are greater than 3 and also greater than four (the adjacent four on the right) then they get highlighted. The adjacent value will change and not always be four. I need to do this in VBA and I want the code to work in such a way that when I move to another line of data similar to the one above the two conditions are tested and the correct values are highlighted. So this is what I have written so far in VBA.

```
Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=AND(ABS(RC) >3,ABS(RC) >RC[9])"
  Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
```

The problem:

I am using the R1C1 format as I want it to update automatically when I apply this code to another row of data. But currently this code only highlights the number 10.2 and not the 6.26 as well as it should. I think that if I leave the code as ABS(RC) this will refer to the current cell value? Please advise. Also the number 4 (adjacent cell) is nine columns from the first value -1.2 - hence me writing RC[9].

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are trying to change reference for 1 condition with each cell but keep the reference for the 2nd condition (checking value of each cell and also checking its value against fixed last cell).

I used

```
Sub highlight()

Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=AND(ABS(RC) >3,ABS(RC) > abs(indirect(address(" & Selection.Row & "," & _
        (Selection.Column + Selection.Columns.Count - 1) & "))))"
Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 45

End Sub
```

1st I select range A1:H1 (that's where I keep your numbers) then I run this macro and I end up with 6.26 and 10.2 highlighted.

Comment: Thanks. Two things though: 1) The reference for the second condition is also relative (not fixed) 2) I won't have the column containing the second condition highlighted and if I try the code you graciously provided without highlighting the column with the second condition i.e. H1 in your worksheet then it highlights the wrong values (3.27 is also highlighted). The indirect address bit is also a bit complex. What I want is for the cells that I have selected to be highlighted if the absolute value of that cell is greater than the value of the second condition (and greater than 3 - condition 1)

Comment: Why do I have to highlight the adjacent value for this to work? i.e. the cell containing the second condition?